# Jboss 8 Wildfly and Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, playframework-2.0, wildfly-8

I'm using Play Framework and I created a .war file using Play2-War to deploy on JBoss 8,
my Play application is using a jar that use Spring. 
I'm using class configuration for spring.

The Problem:
When I deploy the war and try to enable it, it shows me jboss error that caused by spring error.

The JBoss error:

```
JBAS014671: Failed Service
```

The Spring Error:

```
Error creating bean with name EntityManagerFactory in Global...
(The configuration class)
... Invocation of init method failed.
```

I have the spring jars in my war, so i don't know what can cause this exception.

I also tried removing the jars of Spring and adding Spring module to Wildfly, I added the module to the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` but when I load the jar, it could not find the module in JBoss.  Do I need to run the module somehow?